# Compare between 2 tables in 2 different databases

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I have 2 access databases one called `revision` and the other called `revision2`. Each database has a table called `batch`.

I have `DataGridView` that shows the data in the first database.

I need to compare between the 2 tables from the different databases and what matches get a green color in the `DataGridView`.

I used that code but it only colors the first match not all,

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\revision.accdb");
    OleDbConnection con2 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\revision2.accdb");
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * From batch", con);
    OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("select * From batches", con2);
    con.Open();
    con2.Open();
    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    OleDbDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
    dr2.Read();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("batch_no");
    if (dr["batch_no"].ToString() == dr2["batch_no"].ToString())
    {
        string num = dr["batch_no"].ToString();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow myrow in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(myrow.Cells[0].Value) == num)
            {
                myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        con.Close();
        con2.Close();
    }
}
```

Any solution to get what all what matches and color it? Or any better ideas?

Comment: @MitchWheat Does those redgate tools provide api to run compare2 rdbms tables on demand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not loop through the reader(dr), the one you are supposed to find the matching values with your current grid.

Anyway, what's the DataTable and the other reader (dr2) for ?

A quick modification, not yet tested :

```
    if (dr["batch_no"].ToString() == dr2["batch_no"].ToString())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string num = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("batch_no")); //dr["batch_no"].ToString();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow myrow in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(myrow.Cells[0].Value) == num)
                {
                    myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }

        con.Close();
        con2.Close();
    }
```

Comment: i was trying to fill the datatable with the results but faild

Comment: and the dr2 is for the second database i load the data in it is it right ?

Answer (score 0):

u can use "dataview" to check your condition

in this sample "tbl2.DefaultView.FindRows" can be helpful

```
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\revision.accdb");
    OleDbConnection con2 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\revision2.accdb");
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * From batch", con);
    OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("select * From batches", con2);
    con.Open();
    con2.Open();
    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    OleDbDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

    DataTable tbl1 = new DataTable();
    tbl1.Load(dr);

    DataTable tbl2 = new DataTable();
    tbl1.Load(dr2);

    dataGridView1.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "batch_no" };
    dataGridView1.DataSource = tbl1;
    dataGridView1.DataBind();


    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
         if (tbl2.DefaultView.FindRows(dataGridView1.DataKeys[i].Value).Length > 0)
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
```